# Is there a way to watch service calls?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the features I love about ROS's publisher-subscriber design is that I can passively "tune in" to the streams of communication between nodes to better understand their interaction. I have yet to find a convenient way to do the same for services.

I'm working on writing a man-in-the-middle node that could allow me to do this, but this seems like something ROS might provide already. Another option that I have yet to explore is using a debugger, but this could become tedious for a large software pipeline. Does anyone know of something better?

If it informs your answer, I'd like to use parts of the arm_navigation pipeline with existing motor controllers that do not conform to ROS's PR2 controller interface.  Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40476/is-there-a-way-to-watch-service-calls?/) by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no easy way to do introspection of service calls. You might be able to achieve it like a network sniffer though.

However, services are used quite rarely at least in PR2 interfaces since for all longer running processes like execution of arm trajectories, actionlib is used. actionlib is completely based on topics, i.e. you can use rostopic to do introspection.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2